# Anything I put into the fragment overlays the action bar of the fragment. Help me someone

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am a real noob in android studio. I added an imageview and still it covers the action bar.

**This is my main activity.**

```
package com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.navigationdrawervideotutorial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private boolean viewIsAtHome;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    //How to change elements in the header programmatically


    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    displayView(R.id.nav_camara);
}
public void displayView(int viewId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

    switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.nav_camara:
            fragment = new MainFragment();
            title  = getString(R.string.home);
            viewIsAtHome = true;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_touristspot:
            fragment = new TouristFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.t_spot);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_hotels:
            fragment = new HotelFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.hotel);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_mals:
            fragment = new MallsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.malls);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_restaurants:
            fragment = new RestaurantFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.rest);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_govoff:
            fragment = new GovOffFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.govoffz);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_hospitals:
            fragment = new HospitalFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.hospital);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_airport:
            fragment = new AirportFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.airp);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_bust:
            fragment = new BusterminalFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.bterm);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_wharf:
            fragment = new WharfFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.pier);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_helpd:
            fragment = new GalleryFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.helpd);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_rate:
            fragment = new GalleryFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.rus);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_cas:
            fragment = new GalleryFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.com);
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    // set the toolbar title
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    if (!viewIsAtHome) { //if the current view is not the News fragment
        displayView(R.id.nav_camara); //display the News fragment
    } else {
        moveTaskToBack(true);  //If view is in News fragment, exit application
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    displayView(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}
}
```

**This is my mainfragment.java** which I'm having a problem at. I don't really know to how fix it which is my I have concluded and ask a question in stackoverflow.

```
package com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.navigationdrawervideotutorial;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    View myView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        ViewFlipper MyViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)myView.findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
        MyViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
        MyViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(3000);
        MyViewFlipper.startFlipping();
        return myView;
    }
}
```

And finally the fragment_main.xml hope someone will help me.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.compscitutorials.basigarcia.navigationdrawervideotutorial.MainFragment">
<ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zamboanga City!!"/>
    </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code for the activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

This is the xml code for the app_bar_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

[This is the sample output. I just want it to be under the action bar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chmC3.jpg)

Comment: Please add the content of R.layout.activity_main

Comment: Done sir. Sorry about it.

Comment: The activity layout looks incomplete to me. I guess there is a RelativeLayout or something that wraps both the NaviguationView and the included view. Please upload the full file. Also, where is the container for the fragment (id = R.id.fragment_container) ? Is it contained in R.layout.app_bar_main ?

Comment: Yes, fragment_container is contained in app_bar_main. No sir, there is nothing that wraps the navigationview and the included view.

Comment: Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelp